# Firebase and MBED TLSV1.2

Tags: firebase, stm32, tls1.2, google-cloud-functions, mbed

I am having an issue where I can connect to any HTTPS server other than Firebase Cloud Functions.

I found that the error is occurring during the handshake between the client(me) and the server (Firebase) but i have never experienced this during connection to any other servers.

I am using a STM32F105 with a Wiznet W5500 using the mbed TLSV1.2 encryption libraries. Has anyone had experience in a similar situation? Is there any restrictions when connecting to the Firebase Server?

Comment: It does nothing about stm32 even if it run on this platform. You do not mark question with AMD if you ask about linux programs

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the right root CA added? I don't have any Firebase Cloud Functions, but I could successfully connect and download files from https://firebase.google.com using the GeoTrustGlobalCA and [mbed-http](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/sandbox/code/mbed-http/).

Example code here: https://gist.github.com/janjongboom/3db8a6dd00ee23b7ab73f3c0435de853